# Add demo products in onepage checkout order review page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am trying to add a block in one page checkout order review page.

I have the following added in `app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/mypackage/mymodule.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_review>
          <reference name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before">
            <block type="mymodule/mymodule" name="mymodule.mymodule" output="toHtml" template="mymodule/mymodule.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
</layout>
```

Now when I am trying to access the block in `mymodule.phtml` with the code `$this->myFunction();`, I am getting an error undefined variable: `this`

NOTE: `myFunction()` is defined within the block class `MyPackage_Mymodule_Block_Mymodule`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the result of `get_class($this)` ?

Comment: @Raphael at Digital Pianism: Where shall I add this?
In the phtml or in the block?

Comment: In the phtml file. Try echoing the result and see what you get

Comment: @Raphael at Digital Pianism: Can we please start chat for discussing this?

Comment: echoing gives me  MyPackage_Mymodule_Block_Mymodule

Comment: What if you remove `output="toHtml" ` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38127/discussion-between-anurag-khandelwal-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).

Comment: Anyone else who can help here?